# Stuck new request when html5 audio player buffering

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, audio-player

when a html5 audio player in buffering and I call new request my new request stuck until buffering in my page finished!

[image]

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Media Source API or Media Source Extensions (MSE).

This is a nice article that will give an insight on [that](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mse/seamless-playback).

This is the [Official Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API).

The reason to use Media Source API is that it gives us  more control over how much and how often content is fetched.